# How to close MySql connections using Sqlalchemy and Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I built an API using Flask and I'm using a service (as below) to create my database connections.

```
class DatabaseService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_string = "foo"

    def create_connection(self):
        engine = create_engine(self.connection_string)
        Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
        return Session
```

In my **app.py** I add and remove these sessions to Flask application context (**g**) as the docs suggests.
So I can reference to **g.session** always I need them.

```
def get_session():
    if 'session' not int g:
        session = database_service.create_session()
        g.session = session

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    if 'session' in g:
        g.session.remove()

    return None
```

This way every request has your own session that will close after processing. Am I right?
I don't understand why the connections are still alive on my database after the request is already done.
Always I run the command **show processlist** I can see multiple connections sleeping from my API.

Comment: I just want to understand why the downvote. Anything wrong or confuse? I can edit my question and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem opening and closing sessions per-request

```
my_session = Session(engine)
my_session.execute(some_query)
my_session.close()
```